# Why is the type of integer "3" a float in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am new to MATLAB and am confused with types. Why is 3 the float and not integer??

```
>> isa(3, 'float')
ans =

logical

1

>> isa(3, 'integer')

ans =

logical

0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the MATLAB documentation on [Numeric Types](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html), you can read that

> By default, MATLAB stores all numeric values as double-precision floating point.

Therefore, `isa(3, 'float')` (or `isfloat(3)` ) returns `true`.

You can store a number **explicitly as an integer**:

```
isinteger(uint8(3))
ans =

  logical

   1
```

[This example](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isinteger.html#btfppz5-1) from the MATLAB documentation should also be very helpful.

You can use any of the integer types in MATLAB, which are

```
int8    
int16   
int32   
int64   
uint8   
uint16  
uint32  
uint64
```